# Solr Search Model doesn't work without the dynamic field suffix

Tags: content-search, solr

I have ContentSearch code that works and runs fine using Lucene. When I switch the configs over to Solr, the query fails, and the logs state that the field I'm using in the query doesn't exist.

```
[IndexField("tags")]
public IEnumerable<ID> Tags { get; set; }
```

> 16644 13:34:20 ERROR Solr Error : ["undefined field tags"] - Query
>   attempted: [((_template:(2d7ad1cb107e44158690c03e0b65f90c) AND
>   -_name:("__Standard Values")) AND tags:(fc8ac78af9aa495fb4ee08aca0444e1b))]

Note that the error says 'undefined field tags', but really, this should be `tags_sm` when Sitecore adds the suffix to the query.
Changing `[IndexField("tags")]` to `[IndexField("tags_sm")]` gets it working....but now my code is Search Provider dependent.

Is there something I'm missing to make this work without the suffix? I thought Sitecore would automatically add it in there?

Here is how the query looks:-

```
var filterPredicate = PredicateBuilder.True<ArticleSearchResultItem>()
                .And(x => x.TemplateId == IArticlePageItemConstants.TemplateId && x.Name != "__Standard Values");

if (parameters.TagId != (ID)null && parameters.TagId != ID.Null)
{
   filterPredicate = filterPredicate.And(x => x.Tags.Contains(parameters.TagId));
}

var queryable = searchContext.GetQueryable<ArticleSearchResultItem>();
var searchResults = queryable
                .Where(filterPredicate);
```

This is on Sitecore 8.1 Update-2, using Solr 6.1.0.
Thanks.

Comment: I have always had to modify my custom index fields when switching from Lucene to SOLR. I will be interested if is it possible to do it without. I do notice in habitat switching from 8 to 9 (now SOLR) they did not change the field names. https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/blob/master/src/Foundation/Indexing/code/Constants.cs

Comment: Try to change the `public IEnumerable<ID>` to `public IEnumerable<string>` or `public List<string>`

Comment: I've had the same issue too. Have you tried adding an explicit mapping for `IEnumerable<ID>` in the config, something like this?
<typeMatch type="System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Sitecore.Data.ID]" typeName="idCollection" fieldNameFormat="{0}_sm" multiValued="true" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />

Comment: Maybe this can be solved with a type converter too. I haven't tried it, as I've opted for the approach of adding field type, such as `_sm`.
`[TypeConverter(typeof(IndexFieldEnumerableConverter))]`

Comment: can you please check solr schema.xml and find this field there. You can add tags_* as dynamic field

Comment: The other way is to add "tags" field in solr schema.xml and then use of <copyField source="tags_sm" dest="tags"  />. This way you don't need to change your code.

Answer (score 4):

You must have a typematch for type `IEnumerable<ID>` in your index configuration to make this work. So, create a patch file and include typematch as follow

```
<typeMatch typeName="idIEnumerable"        type="System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[Sitecore.Data.ID, Sitecore.Kernel]]"         fieldNameFormat="{0}_sm"  multiValued="true"    settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider"  />
```

or if you want your property to be `List<ID>` then have below typematch included

```
<typeMatch typeName="idList"        type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Sitecore.Data.ID, Sitecore.Kernel]]"       fieldNameFormat="{0}_sm"  multiValued="true"    settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider"  />
```

---

### Explanation

`tags` would get converted to `tags_sm` in query only if there is a typematch found for that particular type (`IEnumerable<ID>` in your case). You can find out the same by looking at typematchs section for your index configuration in showconfig.aspx.

[image]

Behind the scene `SolrSearchConfiguration` class reads this configuration and it sets the strongly type by calling `Type.GetType(type)` and that works fine with simple types like `DateTime`, `Int32`, `Int64`, `String`, `String[]`, List etc..

[image]

But when type is complex such as `IEnumerable<ID>` then `Type.GetType()` method expect a `AssemblyQualifiedName`. You can get `AssemblyQualifiedName` for any type by just calling `type.GetType()` method.

Answer (score 2):

You could change the default field mapping in your index configuration (i would create a custom indexconfiguration based on the default):

```
sitecore/contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration/fieldMap/typeMatches
```

and remove the suffix from the format (this example is for text fields, you should change it for ID-types):

before:

```
<typeMatch 
    typeName="text"                   
    type="System.String"
    fieldNameFormat="{0}_t"
    cultureFormat="_{1}"
    settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
```

without suffix:

```
<typeMatch 
        typeName="text"                   
        type="System.String"
        fieldNameFormat="{0}"
        cultureFormat=""
        settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
```